# Error handling in mvc3 when view is made of many partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 razor application. I have views which are made of multiple partial views. Controller will have to load the data to all the partial views with the help of different service calls.

Now if any of the service call fails, the entire view should not fail - it should continue to show other partial views. and should show error message for the partial view which failed.

Please note here that I do not want to add individual try catch blocks all over the code. Is there any way to achieve this using global error handling?

Answer (score 0):

If loading data for those partials is an I/O intensive task such as network service calls and order is not important (can be done in parallel) => [asynchronous controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) seems like a good fit for your scenario. You could register multiple asynchronous operations in the controller action and upon success/failure load the corresponding result/error message into the view model.

Answer (score 0):

One easy alternative here is simply include multiple ajax calls to load the partial views on the client side. If one fails, no problem as it is it's own separate request. Use jQuery's .get()  method once your document loads. You can then include multiple wait images and handle each error separately - however you want.